# modularize xamarin form application to be used to be used as shared project/application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, maui

scenario:
writing an app in xamarin form .net maui with 3 different permissions/types of users

1. Teachers
2. Students
3. Public

is there a way I can create the structure so that different pages can be used in a shared environment?
i.e.

1. Teacher Can
   1.1 Search books(shared all 3)
   1.2 Publish Books

2 Student Can
2.1 Search books(shared all 3)
2.2 Request Rent(shared between)
2.3 Buy Books

3. Public
   3.1 Search Books(shared all 3)
   3.2 Request Rent(shared between 2)
   3.3 Use Pcs

there are pages that all 3 can access but there are pages that is unique to the user roles/permission

I know in angular we have modules and routing where modules can be loaded depending on the user roles and can create shared modules that work across all apps.

Is there anything similar in the Xamarin app that can be used instead of IsVisible={Binding isTeacher}
all over the app?

Thanks

tried with IsVisible="{Binding theCondition}", messy approch.

Comment: Neither Xamarin nor MAUI have any built in concept of users/roles

Comment: i already have users and roles coming back in my token when login in, i wanna know how i can use them to show and hide pages/features depending the roles

Comment: There is not any general answer to this - there are lots of ways you could do it.  Build a base VM class that includes User/Role data, and if you have common UI elements all pages, build common base pages or reusable controls that are bound to those VM properties.

Comment: There isn't any direct equivalent to Angular modules. You will either have c# code that loads a different version of a page (create several versions of the page, in separate files), or you will use `IsVisible`. If you add to question an example of the code you did with `IsVisible`, perhaps it can be simplified. How familiar are you with c# classes and inheritance? Knowing how to create a `class with common functionality`, then `subclass it for each different case`, is vital for developing a clean solution.

Comment: I think that depends on how you design your UI. Since you know the three roles from login, it just like set three modes in the app. Abstract a base class and other three modes subclass the base mode. Probably you have to create custom controls for each roles.